# Jquery ajax div not updating for db update

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am using a dialog box to update my database and remove services.

Unfortunately it only works for the first "remove" click.

So, I click to open the dialog box. am faced with a list of 5 services.

I click to remove the 5th service, the db is updated, the list (inside the dialog) reloads and the select tag (on the main page) reloads okay.

If I then repeat this step with the 4th service nothing happens, none of: db update, list update and select update

My jquery handler is below, does anycody know why this isn't working?

```
$(function () {
    $(".deletesector").click(function () {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var dataString = 'serviceid=' + name;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./ajax/remove-service.php?" + dataString,
            dataType: "html",
            data: dataString,
            success: function (msg) {
                //UPDATE THE SELET BOXES CONTAINING THE SERVICES
                $("#service1-holder").load('./views/service-list1.tmp.php');

                // UPDATE THE LIST OF SERVICE
                $("#list-of-services").load('./views/list-of-services-for-removal.php');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Probably something to do with the services being reloaded, that handler is no longer being bound. Try with event delegation real quick -- `$(document).on("click", ".deletesector", function() {`

Comment: If you want a directory back you need to use two dots. So where you update you div do     .load('../views/list-of-services-for-removal.php');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don't use .click to redo ajax event there. please use .on().

> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set
>   of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method
>   provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For
>   help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(), 
>   .delegate(), and .live(). To remove events bound with .on(), see
>   .off(). To attach an event that runs only once and then removes
>   itself, see .one()

See documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

so your code would be:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.deletesector', function () {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var dataString = 'serviceid=' + name;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./ajax/remove-service.php?" + dataString,
            dataType: "html",
            data: dataString,
            success: function (msg) {
                //UPDATE THE SELET BOXES CONTAINING THE SERVICES
                $("#service1-holder").load('./views/service-list1.tmp.php');

                // UPDATE THE LIST OF SERVICE
                $("#list-of-services").load('./views/list-of-services-for-removal.php');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Can't believe i've been letting this problem bug me for over a week.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to bind the events to new `#service-holder`... did you try that?.

```
$( "#service-holder" ).bind( "click", your_function);
```